# Retrieve correspondent rows when startsWith == TRUE as numeric values

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, slice, startswith

I am trying to write a script for a complete automation of my data.
Here, I am trying to implement a loop in order to search for all the values which start with "Blank" in the name column of my data.frame.

How can I print all the correspondent rows in a vector? 
i.e. I have a value Blank C in the column names at row 5, I want to get a vector with the values of the same row (5) in columns names and the other data columns 3:6, not as NA but as values because the output is NA.

```
for (val in ms.data$Name) {
if(startsWith(val,"Blank")) {
print(list(ms.data[val,3:6]))
  }
}

Example data
Blank 1 05-Apr-17 7:04 PM   5.771899218 4.922906441 219.0199184 7.779938257
Blank 2 05-Apr-17 7:15 PM   4.913695034 4.071889653 2.161167065 2.567102283
```

Thank you

Comment: Look at `?grep` , and if you still need help please post a minimum example.

Comment: If I understand well what you're trying to do, dplyr is a good package for you as it will allow you to use filter() and select().  For example, you could do something like this:
`library(dplyr)
ms.data %>% filter(grepl("Blank", Name)) %>% select(col-you-want, another-col-you-want, third-col-you-want)`

Comment: @IanWesley, thank you. Could you help me with an example of grep?

Comment: @EgoSum Sure.  Please add some example data to your question.  Either build a short data frame that matches your use case or use `dput(head(ms.data,10)`.